# Why are "secure" cookies insecure?

Tags: http, security, cookies, https

The [MDN docs on HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) state:

> A secure cookie is only sent to the server with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol. Even with Secure, sensitive information should never be stored in cookies, as they are inherently insecure and this flag can't offer real protection.

HTTPS requests have their request bodies and all of their headers encrypted with TLS, including the `Set-Cookie:` response header and the `Cookie:` request header. This should prevent third parties from reading or tampering with the cookie values.

**So why are cookies "inherently insecure"?** (Perhaps Mozilla is thinking of someone with access to the user's computer being able to inspect their cookies?)

Answer (score 2):

*Why are cookies "**inherently** insecure"?*

The biggest problem of cookie is: it is stored in user's computer, which leads to many possibilities. The server lost control of the cookie's privacy once it is sent to client. As the cookie data is stored in user's computer, the data can be leaked when:

- Vulnerability in operating system is exploited by attacker.
- Vulnerability in user-agent is exploited by attacker.
- Browser extension can get permission to read cookies (e.g. [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies)). Yes, a notification will be displayed to user, but a lot of people just ignore the alert and click "Yes".
- Cookie can be inspected in browser dev tool, by another people.
- More...

---

For `secure` flag, if you send sensitive information in `secure` cookie to browser, there are still security concerns:

- As long as `httpOnly` flag is not set, all malicious script can read that cookie, and send the information to any server.
- If `domain` setting is not correct, you may leak that sensitive cookie to some interfaces. For example, if the `secure` cookie's `domain` is `/`, then all backend API would receive the sensitive data, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Those are both good points, but they don't seem like they represent inherent insecurity. They do show that the `Secure` directive alone is not sufficient to make a cookie "secure", but not that it *can't* be made secure.

Comment: @NathanLong Ah, I see your point. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Nice points. Some web frameworks make it easy to encrypt the cookie contents, which would reduce the damage if the cookie were stolen, but of course the attacker could still impersonate the user. The same would be true of a stolen API token or any other identifier a server might give a client.

Comment: FYI, this section of the MDN docs has now been corrected: https://github.com/mdn/sprints/issues/2914

Essentially the point here was that making the transport secure does not secure the information "absolutely". For example it is still accessible to access by clients on the hard drive, and javascript if HttpOnly attribute is not set.